# Error in heatmaply package in R

Tags: r, heatmaply

I would like to create an interactive heatmap plot for my dataset (3109 rows and 12 columns) using heatmaply package in R but got below error:
If I remove the rownames I wouldn't get the error but I need to see the names at least in each spot in the graph! So could you please help me?
Thank you.

```
subset of my matrix:d 
            h0_R2.log2 h0_R4.log2 h0_R5.log2 h12_R2.log2 h12_R4.log2
Ltb4r1        -12.42500  -12.42500  -12.42500    -4.47485    -4.32845
Gm34606        -0.04179   -0.11605    0.12281   -12.42500   -12.42500
LOC102634439   -4.82458   -4.89884   -5.07503   -12.42500   -12.42500
LOC102637286  -12.42500  -12.42500  -12.42500   -12.42500   -12.42500
Kcnj16         -1.70357   -1.49772   -2.06093   -12.42500   -12.42500

 clus1 <- hclust(dist(d))
 d2 <- d[clus1$order,]
 heatmaply(d2 , xlab = "", revC = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, titleX = FALSE )

Error in rotate.dendrogram(dend, order = rev(labels(x)
[seriation::get_order(o)])) : 
'order' is neither numeric nor a vector with ALL of the labels (in the order 
 you want them to be)
```

Comment: Can you also print the clus1$order vector?

Comment: You have duplicated rownames. Make them unique.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.